# Using twilio c# client to pass twilio response back

Tags: c#, response, twilio

I am using the [twilio c# wrapper](https://www.twilio.com/docs/csharp/install) and am able to receive communication from twilio.  I am having trouble responding back to twilio with a response and having twilio recognize it.  Currently I am trying to respond with a TwilioResponse.  Anyone have a good example?  This is a WebApi self hosted windows service.

ex.  TwilioResponse().Message("ok");

Answer (score 4):

I have used Same web API you can use the below menioned code but First you have to configure your APP in Twilio UserAccount.

```
 public class WelcomeController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Post(VoiceRequest request)
    {
        var response = new TwilioResponse();

        response.Say("Welcome to Dhaval demo app. Please enter your 5 digit ID.");
        response.Gather(new { numDigits = 5, action = string.Format("/api/Authenticate") });

        return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.Element, new XmlMediaTypeFormatter());
    }

}
```

When I press the 5 digit no then it will lend to Authetication Controller it' look like

```
  public HttpResponseMessage Post(VoiceRequest request)
    {
        var response = new TwilioResponse();

        var validIds = new List<string> { "12345", "23456", "34567" };
        var userId = request.Digits;
        var authenticated = validIds.Contains(userId);

        if (!authenticated)
        {
            response.Say("You entered an invalid ID.");
            response.Hangup();
        }
        else
        {
            response.Say("ID is valid.");

            response.Redirect(string.Format("/api/Name?userId={0}", userId));
        }

        return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.Element, new XmlMediaTypeFormatter());
    }
```

and it's work fine in my side, once again check it properly you have given the correct `AuthToken`

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

After tinkering for a while, this seems to do the trick.

```
var twiml = new TwilioResponse().Message("test");
return TwilioResponse(twiml);

private HttpResponseMessage TwilioResponse(TwilioResponse twilioResponse)
{
    return new HttpResponseMessage()
    {
        Content = new StringContent(twilioResponse.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml"),
        StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK
    };
}
```